# Keeping asset and public path different in vue app for CDN

Tags: vue-cli, vue-cli-3, vue-cli-4

vue has this option [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) which lets an app to be deployed on subpath: *foobar.com/my-path* , making links and every asset accessible via it.

From performance standpoint, I want to enable CDN on my application's assets. How can I use the URL specifically for assets (and not the hyperlinks)?

Example: 
`./my-path/assets/app.js` should become `https://my-staging-cdn.com/my-path/assets/app.js`
`./my-path/url-2.html` should remain the same

The configuration below allows me to set the path and assets directory, but not able to figure out how to set cdn URL for assets

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: ‘/my-path/‘,
  assetsDir: 'assets'
}
```

Cannot do: 
`publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://my-staging-cdn.com/my-path' : '/my-path/'`, as it will change the URL in application's links too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to get the CDN working or assets out of the box. I tried other strategies like pre-rendering or Nuxt, but because of huge number of pages, it wasn't an option.

The objective was to get SEO bots to read rendered page, so I circled out on [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) and deployed it's instance and put it in my reverse proxy behind the application. This worked.